# INNER JOIN with Doctrine "createQueryBuilder" in SF2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having problem creating an SQL Query with CreateQueryBuilder.

I have 2 tables:

- Table **article** with fields: `articleID (PK), tag, created, userID (FK)`
- Table **articlelocale** with fields: `articlelocaleID (PK), articleID (FK), title, body, locale, translated`

In my articlelocale table I have a FK that links to my article table.

Now I would like to select the articles beginning from the article table where locale == ... (from articlelocale table).

This is my beginning but I can't figure it out:

```
$a = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a')
    ->innerJoin('a.articleid', 'ai', 'WITH', 'ai.articleid = :articleid')
    ->where('ai.locale = :locale')
    ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
    ->addOrderBy('a.created', 'DESC');
```

The more I try, the more errors I get... . What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the help! I've added this to my Article Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Articlelocale", mappedBy="articleid", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $articlelocale;

/**
 * Set articlelocale
 *
 * @param \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Articlelocale $articlelocale
 * @return Articlelocale
 */
public function setArticlelocale(\DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Articlelocale $articlelocale = null)
{
    $this->articlelocale = $articlelocale;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get articlelocale
 *
 * @return \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Articlelocale
 */
public function getArticlelocale()
{
    return $this->articlelocale;
}
```

This is the relation between `Article<->ArticleLocale` in my Articlelocale Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Article
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DX\MurisBundle\Entity\Article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="articleID")
 * })
 */
private $articleid;
```

This is the query in my ArticleRepository:

```
$a = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
     ->select('a')
     ->innerJoin('a.articlelocale', 'ai')
     ->where('ai.locale = :locale')
     ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
     ->addOrderBy('a.created', 'DESC');

if (false === is_null($limit))
    $a->setMaxResults($limit);

return $a->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

I don't get any errors but when I want to loop through my articles and get the ArticleLocale like this:

```
$articles = $em->getRepository('MurisBundle:Article')->getLatestArticles(null, $locale);

foreach($articles as $article)
{
    dump($article->getArticlelocale()); die;
}
```

The result of this is a PersistentCollection...
[image]

I would like to have an actual Articlelocale object .. What am I doing wrong?

That's not really a big problem, but I also get NL and EN but I filter 'where locale == nl'. But I still get two results.

Comment: In the query you have to use the name of property described in your entity, not the name of your field.

Comment: The name of my property in my entity is articleid ..

Comment: can you post the code of your entity?

Comment: Check below how entities should look like

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use directly table column name when dealing with doctrine you have to write DQL its difference from SQL you have use property name that you have defined in your entities also the join part  should have property that points to your second entity then you can create your query as

```
$DM = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$DM->createQueryBuilder('ar')
    ->select('ar')
    ->from('Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Article','ar')
    ->innerJoin('ar.articlelocale', 'lo')
    ->where('lo.locale = :locale')
    ->setParameter(':locale', $locale)
    ->orderBy('ar.created', 'DESC');
```

And in your article entity should have a relation with `Articlelocale` entity something like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Articlelocale", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $articlelocale;
```

And your `Articlelocale` entity should point back to `Article` entity as below

```
/**
 * @var \Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Article
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="articleID")
 * })
 */
protected $article;
```

Also generate getters ans setter for above properties

Edit another way to rewrite you query as

```
$article= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Article');
$article->createQueryBuilder('ar')
    ->select('ar')
    ->innerJoin('ar.articlelocale', 'lo')
    ->where('lo.locale = :locale')
    ->setParameter(':locale', $locale)
    ->orderBy('ar.created', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've changed my entities and query but now I'm getting another small error, what could be the problem of this?

Comment: @nielsv i have added another way to rewrite query as also i have updated aliases

Comment: I'm using the query in a custom repository so I don't have access to ->getDoctrine() because it doesn't extend a Controller.. How could I fix this?

Comment: @nielsv ok in first query remove `->from(..)` part and i guess this will work for you

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I do $article->getArticleLocale() I get a PersistentCollection. What could be the problem of this? (I've updated my topic for more clarity.

Comment: @nielsv this is another question if you have a new question then ask new one if you update your question with newer problem then the answers for this question might become wrong or irrelevant for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

In your ArticleRepository:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a')
    ->innerJoin('a.articlesLocale', 'al')
    ->where('al.articleLocaleId = :localeId')
    ->setParameter('localeId', $locale)
    ->addOrderBy('a.created', 'DESC');
```

Your entities should look like:

```
class Article
{
    private $articleId;

    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="path\to\ArticleLocale", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $articlesLocale;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getArticleId()
    {
        return $this->articleId;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArticleLocale
     */
    public function getLocale(){
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArticleLocale $locale
     */
    public function setLocale($locale){
        return $this->locale = $locale;
    }

}

class ArticleLocale
{
    private $articleLocaleId;

    /**
     * @var ArticleLocale
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="path\to\Article", inversedBy="articlesLocale")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="articleId", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getArticleLocaleId()
    {
        return $this->articleLocaleId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticles(){
        return $this->articles;
    }

}
```